Securing my WS using stunnel and letsencrypt, "Peer suddenly disconnected"
Some background:
I had a wss server before that works in perl without stunnel. I forgot when it stopped working but it probably had a lot to do with how browsers no longer trust self-signed certificates. So I tried to remove the SSL part on my program, stick to non-secure WS, and then use stunnel to secure it. Right now, my program works as ws:// but who wants an insecure ws.
My current setup:
I created a certificate using "Let's Encrypt" for the domain we will call it www.example.com here. I also used the same certificate on my web browser. If I go to my browser and visit the domain, it properly identifies the website as "Connection is secure." At this point, we established that the browser accepts my certificate.
The same certificate is now being used on my stunnel, and this is my stunnel.conf
; Certificate/key is needed in server mode and optional in client mode
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
CApath = /etc/stunnel/cacerts/
verify=4

; Some security enhancements for UNIX systems - comment them out on Win32
chroot = /var/run/stunnel/
; PID is created inside the chroot jail
pid = /stunnel.pid

; Socket parameters tuning
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:SO_KEEPALIVE=1
socket = r:SO_KEEPALIVE=1

; Some debugging stuff useful for troubleshooting
debug = 7
foreground = yes

; Service-level configuration
[mywss]
accept  = 0.0.0.0:8697
connect = localhost:8081

My /etc/stunnel/cacerts folder contains letsencryptauthorityx1.der I downloaded with :
(might not have anything to do with my problem, just establishing my setup)
wget https://letsencrypt.org/certs/letsencryptauthorityx1.der

This is my websocket.html (the basic websocket test you can get from the net):
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var wsUri = "wss://www.example.com:8697";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    //websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

  function sendChatbox(){
    var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox").value;
    doSend(chatbox);
  }
  </script>

  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
  <input type="text" id="chatbox">
  <button onclick="sendChatbox();">Send</button>
  <div id="output">

To emphasize, I'm using "domain name" and not "IP" when connecting to my "ws-over-stunnel" server, which is the common troubleshooting entry I find over the internet, i.e. the browser does not match the certificate name so it throws an error.
When I run my stunnel, this is what I get:
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Clients allowed=500
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.56 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Running  with OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6,SYSTEMD TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI Auth:LIBWRAP
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: errno: (*__errno_location ())
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Compression disabled
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: No PRNG seeding was required
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Initializing service [mywss]
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Ciphers: HIGH:!aNULL:!SSLv2:!DH:!kDHEPSK
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: TLSv1.3 ciphersuites: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: TLS options: 0x02100004 (+0x00000000, -0x00000000)
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Loading certificate from file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Certificate loaded from file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Loading private key from file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Private key loaded from file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Private key check succeeded
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: DH initialization not needed
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: ECDH initialization
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: ECDH initialized with curves X25519:P-256:X448:P-521:P-384
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Binding service [mywss]
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Listening file descriptor created (FD=10)
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Setting accept socket options (FD=10)
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Option SO_REUSEADDR set on accept socket
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[ui]: Service [mywss] (FD=10) bound to 0.0.0.0:8697
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG5[ui]: Switched to chroot directory: /var/run/stunnel/
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[ui]: Created pid file /stunnel.pid
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[cron]: Cron thread initialized
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[cron]: Executing cron jobs
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG6[cron]: Cron jobs completed in 0 seconds
2024.08.14 08:23:49 LOG7[cron]: Waiting 86400 seconds

Take note of my stunnel version: stunnel 5.56
I've seen an answer that doesn't have any upvotes or comments, so I do not know if it is a valid solution. To quote:
"For anyone who still encounter this problem. You need to downgrade your client version according to the server version. In my case downgrading to Stunnel 5.53 solved the peer suddenly disconnected error."
source: Stunnel "Peer suddenly disconnected" error with QuickFix/n
I still would like to know if this is indeed the only solution.
So far so good. When I attempt to run my wss web client, this is what I get:
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[ui]: Found 1 ready file descriptor(s)
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[ui]: FD=4 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[ui]: FD=10 events=0x2001 revents=0x1
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[ui]: Service [mywss] accepted (FD=3) from 124.106.143.113:6258
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Service [mywss] started
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Setting local socket options (FD=3)
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Option SO_KEEPALIVE set on local socket
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG5[0]: Service [mywss] accepted connection from 124.106.143.113:6258
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG6[0]: Peer certificate required
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): before SSL initialization
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): before SSL initialization
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Initializing application specific data for session authenticated
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: SNI: no virtual services defined
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS read client hello
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS write server hello
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS write certificate
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3/TLS write finished
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): TLSv1.3 early data
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG3[0]: SSL_accept: Peer suddenly disconnected
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG5[0]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Deallocating application specific data for session connect address
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Local descriptor (FD=3) closed
2024.08.14 08:26:04 LOG7[0]: Service [mywss] finished (0 left)

It never reaches the part where it connects to my websocket server. The client immediately disconnects and I don't see any other clue except for the console log on the browser saying this:
websocket.html:25 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.example.com:8697/' failed: 
testWebSocket   @   websocket.html:25
init    @   websocket.html:20

Just to make this entry complete, this is my perl program (also your basic/standard test script you can find over the net):
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::WebSocket::Server;

my $origin = 'https://www.example.com';

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
        listen => 8081,
        on_connect => sub {
                my ($serv, $conn) = @_;
                print qq{on connect\n};
                $conn->on(
                        handshake => sub {
                                my ($conn, $handshake) = @_;
                                print qq{handshake: $handshake->req->origin eq $origin?\n};
                                $conn->disconnect() unless $handshake->req->origin eq $origin;
                        },
                        utf8 => sub {
                                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                                print qq{utf8\n};
                                $_->send_utf8($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
                        },
                        binary => sub {
                                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                                print qq{binary\n};
                                $_->send_binary($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
                        },
                );
        },
)->start;

If anyone can lead me to a solution on how to use stunnel on my ws, or at least point me to a debugging method I can use, I'd be grateful.
[ADDEMDUM]
While waiting for answer, I tried to play around with the old codes I had. It seems the old program should still work if using proper certificate:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::WebSocket::Server;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $origin = 'https://www.example.com';
# https://www.examples.com/websocket.html

my $ssl_server = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    Listen             => 5,
    LocalPort          => 8697,
    Proto              => 'tcp',
    SSL_startHandshake => 0,
    SSL_cert_file      => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem',
    SSL_key_file       => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem',
) or die "failed to listen: $!";

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
        #listen => 8081,
        listen => $ssl_server,
        on_connect => sub {
                my ($serv, $conn) = @_;
                print qq{on connect\n};
                $conn->on(
                        handshake => sub {
                                my ($conn, $handshake) = @_;
                                print qq{handshake: $handshake->req->origin eq $origin?\n};
                                $conn->disconnect() unless $handshake->req->origin eq $origin;
                        },
                        utf8 => sub {
                                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                                print qq{utf8\n};
                                $_->send_utf8($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
                        },
                        binary => sub {
                                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                                print qq{binary\n};
                                $_->send_binary($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
                        },
                );
        },
)->start;

With that, it doesn't matter now if I can make stunnel work or not, but I'm still curious how this is done with stunnel.
